# Elmah and SQL Server Compatibility Mode 90

Tags: elmah

The script to setup up the SQL Server database for Elmah has a warning message that says the database is designed to work under SQL Server Compatibility Mode 80 (SQL Server 2000).  Does anyone know if there are any problems in running the script to build the database on a Compatibility Mode 90 database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no known issues with running the script on a 90 (2005) or 100 (2008) server, so you can remove that line out of the script if you want. It's just because it hasn't been 100% formally tested

We use it in a SQL 2005 server at the moment, but are upgrading to 2008 shortly

Comment: Thanks, that's what we thought, but just wanted to check to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Elmah with Sql Server 2008 R2 without any problems.